# Confused by ordering requirements that seem to conflict

Tags: sql, oracle

I am doing an exercise and one of the steps says

> Add the manager id to the previous result after the salary. Order the result first by department id (ascending), then by salary (descending) within departments****  and then by manager id within salary (ascending).

So I can do this up until the asteriks (*). When it says "and then by manager id within salary (asc)" what does that even mean? Like I'm so confused at this point - how can I order by salary descending, then salary by ascending and what does it mean by WITHIN manager ID?

My current code looks like:

```
select 
 first_name || ' ' || last_name  "Full Name", 
 departments.department_id, 
 salary, job_title, 
 departments.department_name, 
 departments.manager_id   
from jobs
 join employees
on jobs.job_id = employees.job_id
 join departments 
on employees.department_id = departments.department_id 
order by department_id, salary desc
```

What do I do now? Really confused and I can't get help from my lecturer until next week which is too long, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: it's just a misread of the question.  They want you to sort by salary descending, but then by manage id ascending.  The question is poorly phrased; it should have said `and then by manager id (ascending) within salary`.  Either that, or they want you to retrieve the data 3 separate times, with 3 different orderings.  It's a bit ambiguous.

Comment: yeah i think you're right honestly, this lecturer is known for wording things in a very confusing way especially in his latest Java exam.. Thanks a lot for that clarification though :)

Answer (score 2):

It just means that you need to order by managers that have the same salary. Do it so by adding `manager` to your `ORDER BY` clause:

```
ORDER BY department_id ASC, salary DESC, manager_id ASC
```

Comment: Oh no way, thanks a lot for that explanation! Appreciate it , was trying to get my head around that question honestly couldn't get what it was trying to say.